# http client failing to call service with jearsey multipart as an argument

Tags: rest, jersey, httpclient, multipart

Trying to hit Jersey multipart service with httpclient, and seeing some issues. Could you please share your insights to resolve this issue. Below I posted client code, service, stack trace.
Thanks for your support.

It works good when I use below client and register classes. Not finding any facility to register these classes for http client.

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Client     
client.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

CLIENT CODE:

```
final String CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART = "multipart/related";
        final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/octet-stream";
        final String BOUNDARY = "--upload_boundary--";
        String responseStr = "";            
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file_upload", inputStream, ContentType.create(CONTENT_TYPE), "filename");
        
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(finalURL);
        httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART);//+";type="+CONTENT_TYPE+";boundary="+BOUNDARY);
        httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            responseStr = entity.toString();                
            RestHelper.verifyResponse(response, responseStr);   
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            LOGGER.error("ClientProtocolException during upload",e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("IOException during upload",e);
        } finally {
            response.close();
            httpclient.close();             
        }
```

REST SERVICE:

```
@Consumes(MULTIPART_RELATED)
public String addDocument(MultiPart multipart)
```

STACKTRACE:

```
httpResponse :::::::::::::::::::: HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1, $WSEP: , Content-Language: en-US, Transfer-Encoding: chunked, X-Cnection: Close, Date: Mon, 10 May 2021 11:50:32 GMT, Set-Cookie: dev-issapps.us=2036276652.6195.0000; path=/; Httponly] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1,Chunked: true]}}
17:20:32.220 [main] ERROR us.dc.httpproxy.RestHelper - Response Error: RestException{us.dc.httpproxy.RestException
: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', statusCode=400, detail='ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1,Chunked: true]}'} 
17:20:32.221 [main] ERROR us.dc.httpproxy.RestClient - Exception in executeMultiPartRequest http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/applications/GWEW/documents
RestException{ us.dc.httpproxy.RestException: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request', statusCode=400, detail='ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1,Chunked: true]}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, hope it helps somebody:

```
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.13'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.3'
    

try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {

        File file = new File("src/main/resources/48-1.jpg");

        MultipartEntityBuilder entitybuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entitybuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entitybuilder.addBinaryBody("image", new FileInputStream(file), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, file.getName());
        entitybuilder.setContentType(ContentType.create("multipart/related"));

        HttpEntity mutiPartHttpEntity = entitybuilder.build(); 

        RequestBuilder reqbuilder = RequestBuilder.post(url);
        reqbuilder.setEntity(mutiPartHttpEntity);

        HttpUriRequest multipartRequest = reqbuilder.build();

        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(multipartRequest);

        System.out.println("response status = " + httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        System.out.println("filenet id = " + EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity()));

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```